# FlotChart Data Change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using Flotcharts plugin on my website.

I want to use one of the charts. However, I am unsure how the information is being plotted in order to change the information.

Can someone please advise me on how the following coding works / broken up:

```
d1 = [
    [1262304000000, 5], [1264982400000, 200], [1267401600000, 1605], [1270080000000, 1129], 
    [1272672000000, 1163], [1275350400000, 1905], [1277942400000, 2002], [1280620800000, 2917], 
    [1283299200000, 2700], [1285891200000, 2700], [1288569600000, 2100], [1291161600000, 1700]
  ]
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of context in your question, so it's hard to offer much information in an answer, but your array `d1` consists of a set of data points. Each data point has an x-value and a y-value. It looks the x-value is a date/time value and the y-value is a number. (The large numbers such as `1262304000000` look like native JavaScript date/time values; `1262304000000`, for example, is midnight on January 1, 2010.) Other than that, there's not much else we can offer unless you want to add more context.